# How to strip whitespace from url before routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We have callbacks being issued against urls in our rails app with spaces.

Example problem URL:

`www.example.net/my_collection/my_endpoint%20`

The route config:

```
resources :my_collection do
  collection do
    post :my_endpoint
  end
end
```

This causes the request to not match the route for `my_endpoint`. Is there any setting I can change or custom code I can write to make the request match as if there was no whitespace?

Comment: how is the callback getting called with a url that has a space?

Comment: @BM5k Users that are entering a callback in a 3rd party service so not something we can easily fix.

Comment: I think I understand now. Can you share the route definition for the route that should be hit by the callback?

Comment: @BM5k Updated to be more like real app structure complete with route information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) to capture (and potentially ignore) parts of the incoming path

```
resources :my_collection do
  collection do
    post '/endpoint(*junk)' => 'endpoints#create'
  end
end
```